# Nested Serializers - how to access attrs from serializer's field during validate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nested, django-serializer

I created nested serializers and during validate method in parent serializer I don't have any data from child serializer. When i raise error with 'attrs' as message then i get only data from 'pk' and 'name' fields. How can i get data from OpenningTimeSerializer in WarehouseSerializer??

**serializers.py**

```
class OpenningTimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OpenningTime
        fields = ['weekday', 'from_hour', 'to_hour']

class WarehouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    openning_time = OpenningTimeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = ['pk', 'name', 'openning_time']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        raise serializers.ValidationError(attrs)
```

**models.py**

```
class Time(models.Model):

    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(from_hour__lt=F('to_hour')),
                name='%(class)s_check_hours'
            )
        ]


class OpenningTime(Time):

    weekday = models.IntegerField(
        choices=WEEKDAYS)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.get_weekday_display()} {self.from_hour.strftime('%H:%M')}-{self.to_hour.strftime('%H:%M')}"


class Warehouse(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    openning_time = models.ManyToManyField(OpenningTime)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Can you add the content of the `models.py` file here?

Comment: @Metalgear Sure! I edited my post already.

Comment: updated the following line with,  ```openning_time = OpenningTimeSerializer(many=False,read_only=True)```

Comment: @dummyfirst Yes, i tried this alreaady and nothing change after this. I still don't have openning_time fields in attrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I figured this out. I can have access to data from child serializers by self.initial_data, additionally need to convert string data and pass to serializer.

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    openning_data = json.loads(self.initial_data['openning_time'])
    serializer = OpenningTimeSerializer(data=openning_data)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(serializer.errors)
    serializer.data
```